# 'Put the ball' vs 'throw the ball'

Tags: synonyms

Is the word *put* a synonym to *throw*? If a boy exerts his strength to throw a ball, can we also use "put" to describe such? Some online dictionaries define *put* as "throw a force or weight," which is confusing.

Comment: The AHDEL definition of this sense comes closer to being precise than that of say Collins or R K Webster's. What is really required is a list of direct objects normally used with it / actual situations where it is used. As mikeagg says, the usage is very restricted.

Comment: In some contexts "put" might be used, but not generally.  Eg, in (US baseball) pitching practice the catcher may hit his fist into his catcher's mitt, hold it up, and yell "Put 'er there!"  In general (outside of "shot put"), the verb implies causing the ball to successfully hit some target, vs simply being thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you put the ball in the basket, you scored. If you threw the ball at the basket, you could still have missed.  It's a little less confusing if you say you threw the ball *into* the basket, but an emotionally invested team fan might still want some clarification. No such confusion with "put." Plus it's shorter.

Comment: Good point. But the question says nothing about baskets. Mikeagg answers the question for "put the ball" on its own.

Answer (score 1):

That meaning of *put* is really only used in the context of the Shot Put (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shot_put). If you tried to use *put* as a synonym for throw in any other context, you would certainly confuse people.

Comment: Except that the clearly related *putt* is used in golf.